# MongoDB String data became Object

Tags: mongodb

I have data structure for field "TID" which supposed to be String:

```
  "EPC": "8650029665708",
  "TID": "E2806894200050018F35096F",
  "location": "1",
  "status": 1,
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2020-02-04T00:10:51.188Z"
  }
```

And some data of my collection is of correct format above, but some of them somehow have following format:

```
"EPC": "8650029665708",
  "TID": "{ _id: 5e1ed7f0548e4d8a94b87304,\n  TID: 'E2806894200050018F35096F' }",
  "location": "1",
  "status": 1,
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2020-02-04T00:10:51.188Z"
  }
```

Could you suggest me why String became Object and are there any way to fix it?

Comment: did you apply some sort of update on the collections? if yes can you share that?

Comment: I think I might applied this query db.inventories.createIndex({ TID: 1 });

Comment: That `_id` value looks a bit like an ObjectId.  If it is, the timestamp part of it indicates that value was created `2020-01-15 09:14:24Z`. Not sure if that will help.